# Deadlock when using setText on JTextArea in Swing

Tags: java, swing, deadlock, event-dispatch-thread, concurrency

I have the following Java Program which one starts in about 50% of all launch attempts. The rest of the time it seams to deadlock in the background without displaying any GUI. I traced the problem to the setText method of the JTextArea Object. Using another Class like JButton works with setText but JTextArea deadlocks. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what is wrong with the following code:

```
public class TestDeadlock extends JPanel {
private JTextArea text;
TestDeadlock(){
    text = new JTextArea("Test");
    add(text);
    updateGui();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Deadlock");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(new TestDeadlock());
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void updateGui(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Here");
            text.setText("Works");
            System.out.println("Not Here");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Try not to use `invokeLater`. Such behaviour is probably due to absence of dispatching thread, as you have not yet created any window. The one is created when you show it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, now the behavior makes sense to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your main method must be wrapped into `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`, that's basic Swing rule to create [Swing GUI on EventDispashThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setTitle("Deadlock");
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.add(new TestDeadlock());
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, as I am new to swing I wasn't aware of this rule.